# Problems with Netplan's config for Ubuntu Server 18.04.5 for Raspberry Pi

Tags: server, raspberrypi, netplan

So I want to set up an Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu for a robotic Projekt. Im following [this guide](https://medium.com/realroboox/how-to-setup-ros2-on-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-6b77cd350b7a).

Like it says I change the /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml like:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
# Renderer can be 'networkd' or 'NetworkManager'
ethernets:
eth0:
optional: true
dhcp4: false
wifis:
wlan0:
optional: true
dhcp4: true
access-points:
"YOUR-SSID-NAME":
password: "YOUR-PASSWORD"
# uncomment the line below if you're using a Microsoft DHCP Server
#dhcp-identifier: mac
```

Note: I didn't uncomment the last line, as I'm using a macOS system, but not Sure if that's correct.

The Problem is:

If I type:

```
sudo netplan --debug try

sudo netplan --debug generate
```

It gives me the "unkown keywoard "wlan0".

I tried to google the Error, but I'm only finding different kind of errors at the Web. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 3):

**Your .yaml file lacks proper formatting...**

It should look like this... same indentation, spacing, and no tabs:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "YOUR-SSID-NAME":
          password: "YOUR-PASSWORD"
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

**You must also install wpasupplicant...**

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant`

`reboot`

**If your .yaml keeps getting overwritten...**

You may also need to create /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:

```
network: {config: disabled}
```